# Google Contacts V3, retrieving GMail contacts only

Tags: google-contacts-api

I have the following code that works fine.  But the issue is that the call retrieves thousands of contacts (most having only email).  I want to download only those contacts that are listed in "Contacts" tab in GMail. I had to set a high "NumberToRetrieve" and then have to filter those with more information other than just email.

```
Dim cr As New ContactsRequest(settings)
Dim query As New ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"))
query.NumberToRetrieve = 5000
query.OrderBy = ContactsQuery.OrderByLastModified
query.SortOrder = ContactsQuery.SortOrderDescending

Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = cr.Get(Of Contact)(query)
```

As usual this Google API is also poorly designed.  At least in the .Net wrapper of the API I don't see anything that I can use to retrieve only GMail contacts or add a filter such as "where Address exists".  Any inputs?

### EDIT

Based on the feed back, I scrolled through all contacts groups to find the group "Contacts".

```
Dim groupquery As New GroupsQuery(GroupsQuery.CreateGroupsUri("default"))
            Dim fgrp As Feed(Of Group) = cr.Get(Of Group)(groupquery)
            Dim GroupAtomId As String = ""
            For Each gr In fgrp.Entries
                If gr.Title.Contains("Contacts") Then
                    GroupAtomId = gr.Id
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```

then used GroupAtomId,  `query.Group = GroupAtomId`.  Seems to be working ok.

Comment: For retrieving all the contacts from "contacts" tab in Gmail, you have to specify the group value(Group) in the query as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters and also for retrieving just the contacts in "contacts" tab in Gmail, the group value would be just "Contacts" as shown here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#working_with_contact_groups

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to right direction.  If you answer, I will accept.

Comment: Thanks @Allen, added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For retrieving all the contacts from `Contacts` tab in `Gmail`, you have to specify the group value(`Group`) in the query as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters) and also for retrieving just the contacts in `Contacts` tab in `Gmail`, the group value would be just `Contacts` as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#working_with_contact_groups)

Hope that helps!